# I'm getting java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, reflection, byte-buddy

I'm getting following error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of [static java.lang.String com.runtime.MyInterceptor.intercept()] allows for delegation from public java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()

I don't know what mistake I'm doing.

```
public void interceptMethod() throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {
    Class<?> dynamicType = new ByteBuddy().subclass(Object.class)
            .method(ElementMatchers.named("toString"))
            .intercept(MethodDelegation
            .to(MyInterceptor.class))
            .make()
            .load(getClass().getClassLoader(), ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.WRAPPER)
            .getLoaded();

    if (dynamicType.newInstance().toString().equals("intercept")) {
        System.out.println("method intercept() is intercepted by byteBuddy");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Failed to intercept the method toString()");
    }

}

class MyInterceptor {
    static String intercept() {
        return "intercept";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the interceptor method public:

```
public class MyInterceptor {
    public static String intercept() {
        return "intercept";
    }
}
```

Comment: still i'm facing the same problem

Comment: That's strange, Your code is working when i run it with that change. Is MyInterceptor a nested class? Maybe try to make it public static or public if it's top level class.

Comment: Hi Kaos, i made MyInterceptor as publicand  it is working. many thanks for you :)

Comment: are u in linkedin?

Comment: I have an account there, although i log in rarely. BTW please accept the answer if You are satisfied ;>